# Add usercontrols dynamically inside a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, user-controls

Here's my problem. I am trying to add usercontrols dynamically to different rows of a GridView.

Let me explain the scenario further. Let's say, I have a page where the user can place orders for different kinds of items. The order form for each item is different in layout and code, and has its own usercontrol. There is an "Add More" button, which lets the user add an extra row to the GridView, while the kind of form that gets appended is selected by the dropdown list (see picture below). 
[image]
What I am trying to do is - have a separate UserControl for each one of these forms, and then have the UserControl added (or maybe I should say "bound") to the GridView. Every time a new row is added, I plan to re-bind the GridView, including rows from above, to maintain all the rows.

The problem is - the main page cannot know what fields there will be inside each individual UserControl (they can be anything, really, and down the road, newer UCs could be added). So my main question is - how do I bind the data to the GridView, when I do not know what to bind? Is there any way to bind the data from inside each UserControl itself?

I hope my problem and question are clear enough. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I am wondering, what if all your controls confirmed to the same interface. Then you could have a list of controls and data bind to that list - is this something possible? Your list doesn't have to contain same objects but as long as they all derive from same interface, you could bind them all. Just a thought

Comment: Possibly possible. Thanks for the idea!